# Python 3.x Beautiful Soup lagging spider

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I've been tinkering with Beautiful Soup as a hobby/project, and this one seems to be working as intended; scrapes HTML, grabs headline title+link, adds it all to a set, and then iterates and displays in a human-friendly output. I use a set as running a list seems to duplicate every title+link pairing; not sure how to stop it from running twice.

I notice, however, that as soon as I launch the `NYT_Spider()` function, the program stops responding for a short time but does indeed return and display the correct results.

My question is twofold:

1) What, exactly, causes the program to hang upon running the NYT_Spider function, and is this something I can reasonably rectify?

2) The spider does also pull out and print links to articles/advertisements that lack a title, appearing similar to:

```
Nonehttps://www.nytimes.com/2017/11/02/education/edlife/bilingual-mfa-writing.html
```

Is there a simple way to remove those using the current modules, or should I simply regex the results?

Here is the full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def NYT_Spider():

    result_list = set()
    url = "https://www.nytimes.com/section/world/americas"
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': "story-link"}):
        href = link.get('href')
        title = get_single_item_data(href)
        results = str(title) + str(href) + "\n" + "\n"
        result_list.add(results)

    for i in result_list:
        print(i)


def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
    for item_name in soup.findAll('h1', {"class": "headline"}):
        return item_name.string + "\n"

NYT_Spider()
```

Comment: Try highlighting the important pieces of your code and providing example snippets of the data you are crawling. Concise questions will draw more answers if the single problem is understood.

Comment: This is too much code. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I can reduce the code down, will update in a few minutes.